# Ubuntu 16.04 - Keep lag freezing randomly

Tags: 16.04, freeze

It just freeze for like 1-3 seconds on every operation, browsing chrome, editing images, with literly everything, Is it really a partition problem? Or what could be the problem?

After `fdisk -l` :

```
/dev/sda1  *          2048     206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2           206848  634882047 634675200 302.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        634882048 1106899631 472017584 225.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1106900990 1149868031  42967042  20.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1106900992 1110806527   3905536   1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       1110808576 1149868031  39059456  18.6G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Why would it be a "partition problem" and what is that exactly anyway?

Comment: Open a `terminal` and type `top` and what which processes come to the top every 1-3 seconds. Maybe you'll catch it. Do you have the same thing occur when using the Guest account?

Comment: @CelticWarrior, I do not know, I googled the problem and most of the solutions was about partition problems!

Comment: it might be worth it to also run 'glances' in terminal. Will show memory/swap behavior. I am running with a comparatively small RAM (1GB) and spent some time exploring info on swap in Linux systems. do a search in fav engine 'Linux swap' - should find good info that may help with your problem.